# Swift - Changing UIView programmatically while keeping IBOutlets (File's Owner)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Here is a rough sketch to help understand what I'm trying to do:
[image]

I have a MainViewController that has a single UIView (MainView)

I have a .xib UIView (called Window) that contains two controls:

1. segmentedController - with four segments
2. UIView (called WindowUIView) - that will change depending upon the segment that is chosen

There are also four independent .xib UIViews (each with their own IBOutlets and IBActions) that will load into the WindowUIView (which subsequently loads into the MainViewController's UIView).

When '**Option 1**' is chosen from the segmentedController I would like to load **Option1UIView** into the **WindowUIView** and execute the code contained within **Option1UIView.swift**.

When '**Option 2**' is chosen from the segmentedController I would like to load **Option2UIView** into the **WindowUIView** and execute the code contained within **Option2UIView.swift**.

etc etc etc for Option 3 & Option 4

So far, I have successfully connected the **File's Owner -> Custom Class -> Class** fore each one of the Option#UIViews (in their *.xib) to the appropriate Option#UIView.swift

The MainViewController has its MainView **Custom Class -> Class** set to Window
The Window.xib has its WindowUIView **Custom Class -> Class** set to Window
The Window's UIView (WindowUIView) **File's Owner -> Custom Class -> Class** is set to Option1UIView

When the app is run in the simulator, things work as expected:
MainViewController has its MainView changed to the Window's, which in turn has its view changed to Option1UIView. 
All of the IBOutlets and IBActions are working properly for Option1UIView.

However, when I chose a different segment, the appropriate Option#UIView is loaded in WindowUIView (good), but the code is no longer connected. The app crashes because the .xib files are unable to find the connections (IBOutlets & IBActions) in their respective files (*.swift) that used to be attached to the File's Owner. It's as if the File's Owner has been deleted.

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the error:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key View (from the Option#UIView swift file).

Update: 
Here is the code inside Window.swift

```
class Window: UIView {
@IBOutlet var View: UIView! // Full view
@IBOutlet weak var Controller: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var View: WindowUIView! // The subView

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Window", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.View)
}

@IBAction func controllerSwitch(sender: AnyObject) {
    let value = Controller.selectedSegmentIndex
    switch value {
        case 0 : print("Option1")
            NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Option1UIView", owner: self, options: nil)
            self.WindowUIView.addSubview(self.View)
        case 1 : print("Option2")
            NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Option2UIView", owner: self, options: nil)
            self.WindowUIView.addSubview(self.View)
        case 2 : print("Option3")
            NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Option3UIView", owner: self, options: nil)
            self.WindowUIView.addSubview(self.View)
        case 3 : print("Option4")
            NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Option4UIView", owner: self, options: nil)
            self.WindowUIView.addSubview(self.View)

        default : print("Out of bounds")
    }
}
```

I also have an extension to help load the Nib files:

```
extension UIView
{
    class func loadNibNamed(nibNamed: String, bundle : NSBundle? = nil) -> UIView? {
        return UINib(
            nibName: nibNamed,
            bundle: bundle
            ).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you load option2UiView etc from the nib files

Comment: I've added some additional code. I would think this is a fairly standard procedure... but maybe not???

Comment: It is a fairly standard procedure, which is why I wanted to see the code as to how you were doing it.  You have a couple of problems.  1) You are loading the nib but not doing anything with the view that is loaded (which is returned by `loadNibNamed`) and 2) you are adding your own view as a sub view repeatedly.  `WindowUIView` should be an outlet of type `UIView` to which you simply assign the view returned by `loadNibNamed`

Comment: I'm a bit lost. I totally get your point #2 (dumb mistake on my part). But I'm not exactly sure how to assign the view that is returned from loadNibNamed? I assume you would do something like:     var tempNib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Option3UIView", owner: self, options: nil)
            WindowUIView = tempNib[0] as! UIView     Obviously it isn't working, and when the loadNibNamed code is executed it crashes due to not finding the proper IBOutlets. I appreciate your help Paul

Comment: It is probably better use a container view and load a UIViewController instance into it. - You can use `initWithNibName` on a new instance of your UIViewController subclass